# YouTube comments notification

Tags: youtube, notifications, comments

I used to get notifications from various comments that were replying to me or were in the same comment chain. But suddenly the notification (little bell icon) started displaying only YouTube videos that were uploaded by my sub channels (the ones where I chose to get notified). To avoid that I disabled the notification from upload. But the notifications don't change at all. If I click on a notification for a video and I see the video the notification doesn't go away. Those specific notifications have gotten stuck in there. The settings don't have anything to address this and I just cant get notifications from comments anymore.

Is this a bug? This didn't happen gradually. One day I went to my notifications and they are just stuck that way ever since ,the same specific notifications. Even though I had enabled the video notifications much earlier in various channels. But they just got there all together and they cant be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The old bell was part of Google+. Google+ is getting removed from YouTube, so the bell, too, had to go. The new bell does feature videos (ie it mirrors push notifications you might get on your phone), and doesn't support in-line replies yet.

You can set upload notification on a per-channel basis on youtube.com/subscription_manager (the bells next to the subscribe button), and you can set whether you want comments on your videos and comment replies in your bell on youtube.com/account_notifications.

If you have feature requests or discovered a bug, do send feedback to let the developers know. You can send feedback at the bottom of any YouTube page (old design) or at the bottom of the sidebar (new design).